# PDF of Y=sin^2(X)

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory

Suppose X ∼ Exponential(λ). Find the PDF of $$Y = sin^2(X)$$
Note: While the solution involves an infinite sum, it is an example of a geometric series and so can be evaluated.

My answer so far:
I was able to go as far as finding the bounds, and now I am stuck on the integral itself. As in the directions, we are told to use a geometric series, but I don't know how to proceed from here.

The integral which will give me the CDF

I also have the piece $$P(0 <= x <= arcsin(\sqrt t))$$ I know this does not included in the integral, but I don't know how to incorporate it into my CDF.

$$\int_a^b \lambda\ e^-\lambda x\ \,dx,$$ 
$$ a = k \pi\ - arcsin(\sqrt t)$$ 
$$ b = k \pi\ + arcsin(\sqrt t)$$

Comment: Just for reference, someone else is asking the same thing [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230199/derived-distribution-pdf-of-sin2x). I think one of these might be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem of finding derived distribution, so

$$CDF_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(\sin^2(X)\leq y)$$

Now it is time to draw the plot of $\sin^2(x)$ for $x>0$ and see how to calculate this probability; for $0\leq y \leq 1$ it is
$$P(\sin^2(X)\leq y)=\int_{0}^{\arcsin{\sqrt{y}}}{\lambda e^{-\lambda x}} dx+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{k\pi-\arcsin{\sqrt{y}}}^{{k\pi+\arcsin{\sqrt{y}}}}{\lambda e^{-\lambda x}} dx$$

The integrals are simple, and the sum is the sum of geometric series.