# Derived distribution: PDF of $\sin^{2}(x)$

Tags: statistics, trigonometry, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

I want to find the PDF of $Y = \sin^2(X)$, where $X ∼ \text{Exponential}(\lambda)$ is a random variable. I thought i had solved this correctly by simply finding the inverse $h(Y) = X$ and taking the derivative via the chain rule. However, I was told that the solution of this problem would involve an infinite sum, but my solution did not, so I assume it was wrong. I can see why there would be an infinite sum due to the adding up of all the sine intervals, but I could not seem to figure out how to find an expression for each of these intervals that I can then sum up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: please show us your solution any way

Comment: I guess you and [this person](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230176/pdf-of-y-sin2x) are the same or in the same class. If you're the same person, please don't post your question twice.

Comment: By the way, it's not one-to-one, so you can't just find the inverse and take the derivative.

Comment: I am not the same person and when I was searching this other question did not come up but thank you for poitning that out!
But yeah it not being one-to-one is exactly my problem, so how would you proceed in this case?

Comment: could you just find the inverse in one interval from 0 to $pi$ and find the derivatrive of the intergral with the chain rule and then sum up all the intervals that follow? But I am unsure how to deal with the negative part then.

Comment: You are close. So you can first apply the double angle formula $\displaystyle \sin^2(x) = \frac {1 - \cos(2x)} {2}$. Then, inside the support of $X$ (i.,e. $\mathbb{R}^+$), you partition it into many intervals such that in each interval the transformation is one-to-one. So in particular the length of such interval is $\pi/2$. Then you can apply the Jacobian technique repeatedly for all the intervals, and then sum the resulting pdfs, weighted by the probability of $X$ falling into that interval. And this is just the law of total probability.